# Loading partial entities with Linq to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity, loading, classloader, entityobject

I am trying to load a partial entity with Linq to Entities:

```
Dim contacts = From c In My.Context.Contacts _
     Select New Contact With { _
         .ContactId = c.ContactId, _
         .Name = c.Name
     }
```

I tried it and I get the following NotSupportedException: "*The entity or complex type 'CompleteKitchenModel.Contact' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.*"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use anonymous type:

```
Dim contacts = From c In My.Context.Contacts _
 Select New With { _
     .ContactId = c.ContactId, _
     .Name = c.Name
 }
```

and then copy data to Contact list:

```
For Each contact In contacts    
     Dim c As New Contact With { .ContactId = c.ContactId, .Name = c.Name}
     //Add to list
Next
```

Your syntax, as error says, is not supported.

Comment: +1. Alternately, project onto a POCO, which is supported in L2E.

Comment: @Craig Fisher: And where did I wrote something about syntax error?

Comment: @Craig Stuntz, @Craig Fisher, @LukLed, please refer to [my related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5985357 "DTOs in WCF RIA Services Master-Detail") on how to load partial queries using L2E across the wire with RIA Services.